# How to activate a bash script with a sublime text build system in os x?

Tags: bash, sublimetext3

I want to execute this simple bash script with a JSON BUILD SYSTEM  in Sublime Text.

```
#!/bin/bash

open -a Google\ Chrome ~/website/frontpage.html 
open -a Sublime\ Text ~/website/javascript.js
```

---

This sublime text build system does not activate the script above. How do I get it do run `simplebashscript.sh` (the script above)?

```
//build system
{

 "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "sh ~/simplebashscript.sh"]

}
```

Comment: please explain why you are down voting me so I don't make the mistake in future!

Comment: I didnt downvote but post doesn't really contain a question, is very broad in what you may want, and also doesn't include what `doesn't work` means.

Comment: thankyou I didn't realise I will try and define my question more precisely

Answer (score 1):

## This solution works on os x.

```
{
    "cmd"       : ["sh ~/simplebashscript.sh"],
    "selector"  : "source.shell",
    "shell":"bash"
}
```

Comment: `"shell": "bash"` is not a valid [build system option](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html#exec-command-arguments). It should either be `true` or not present. The items in the `"cmd"` array need to be individually surrounded by quotes, and separated by commas. If you set the executable bit on your `.sh` file, you don't need to call it with `sh`, you just need to put the name of the file there.